# How to draw and move a square in XNA?

Tags: c#, graphics, xna

I'm trying to draw a square in XNA and simply move it around with the keyboard, based on user input. Unfortunately, I haven't even been able to get the square to show - I'm positive I'm missing something here, but I can't figure out exactly what it is. I plan to create a complicated hierarchy of primitive shapes which I can use in my game. The main components of the `Shape` class are initialized, and the deriving class (in this case `Rect`) utilizes these components for further use, and configures them.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Code**

*Shape.cs*

```
public abstract class Shape
    {
        public Vector3 Center;
        public Color[] Colors;
        public bool SetColorsOnUpdate;

        public virtual Rectangle BoundingBox { get; set; }
        public float Radius { get { return mRadius; } }

        protected VertexBuffer mVertexBuf;
        protected IndexBuffer mIndexBuf;
        protected float mRadius;
        protected BasicEffect mShader;

        public Shape(Vector3 center, Color[] colors, int numVertices, float radius)
        {
            Colors = colors;
            Center = center;
            mVertexBuf = new VertexBuffer(Graphics.MainDevice, typeof(VertexPositionColor), numVertices, BufferUsage.WriteOnly);
            mIndexBuf = new IndexBuffer(Graphics.MainDevice, IndexElementSize.SixteenBits, numVertices, BufferUsage.WriteOnly);
            SetColorsOnUpdate = true;
            mShader = new BasicEffect(Graphics.MainDevice);
            mRadius = radius;
        }

        public abstract void Update();
        public abstract void Draw();
    }
```

**Rect.cs**

```
public class Rect : Shape
{
    public override Rectangle BoundingBox
    {
        get
        { 
            int x = (int)Center.X, y = (int)Center.Y;
            int diameter = (int)mRadius * 2;

            return new Rectangle(
                x, y,
                x + diameter, 
                y + diameter
            );
        }
    }

    const float TestRectZCoordinate = 0;
    const int NumVertices = 4;

    public Rect(Vector3 center, Color[] colors, float radius)
        : base(center, colors, NumVertices, radius)
    {
        if (colors.Length < NumVertices)
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException(string.Format("Color array passed to Rect constructor MUST have an element index size of 4. Current length passed is {0}", colors.Length));

        mShader.VertexColorEnabled = true;

        mVertexBuf.SetData<VertexPositionColor>(
                new VertexPositionColor[]
                {
                    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(Center.X + mRadius, Center.Y + mRadius, TestRectZCoordinate), Colors[0]),
                    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(Center.X + mRadius, Center.Y - mRadius, TestRectZCoordinate), Colors[1]),
                    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(Center.X - mRadius, Center.Y - mRadius, TestRectZCoordinate), Colors[2]),
                    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(Center.X - mRadius, Center.Y + mRadius, TestRectZCoordinate), Colors[3])
                }
            );

        mIndexBuf.SetData<short>(new short[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 });
    }

    public override void Update()
    {
        //TODO
    }

    public override void Draw()
    {
        mShader.World = Matrix.CreateWorld(Center, Vector3.Forward, Vector3.Up);
        mShader.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();

        Graphics.MainDevice.SetVertexBuffer(mVertexBuf);
        Graphics.MainDevice.Indices = mIndexBuf;

        Graphics.MainDevice.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 0, NumVertices, 0, 1);
    }
}
```

**Update**

Here is the latest Rect.Draw() implementation.

```
public override void Draw()
    {
        Viewport viewport = Graphics.MainDevice.Viewport;

        mShader.World = Matrix.CreateWorld(Center, Vector3.Forward, Vector3.Up);
        mShader.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(viewport.Width / 2, viewport.Height / 2, -5f), Center, Vector3.Up);
        mShader.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();

        Graphics.MainDevice.SetVertexBuffer(mVertexBuf);
        Graphics.MainDevice.Indices = mIndexBuf;

        Graphics.MainDevice.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.LineStrip, 0, 0, NumVertices, 0, 2);
    }
```

Comment: Did you set up your camera properly so that the shape is visible??

Comment: @PaulG, I believe so. I'm not quite sure if I did that properly, or if I need to even do that. It's a 2D game - therefore do I *need* a camera?

Comment: Yes it is necessary. Please post your projection matrix/World matrix.

Comment: All of my 2D XNA projects were based on sprites, so I've never actually tried it the way you're trying it. But I do know that only one face of the triangle will be drawn, make sure your visible face is the side the camera is pointing at. Try rotation the triangle to see.

Comment: There is a small piece of code in my question that could give you a start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091163/simple-xna-2d-demo-why-is-my-f-version-slower-than-c-sharp-version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah - I think I see at least one of your problem(s). You're drawing a TriangleList (see [PrimitiveType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.primitivetype.aspx)) and you need 6 indices, not 4.

Got it. It looks like your vertex/index order was wrong. I also didn't see a projection matrix.

Here's the code that worked great for me - all I did was to add a projection matrix, reorder the vertices, change the indices and fix the primitive count.

http://pastebin.com/tMKCxBLL

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also if you're drawing a square you'll want 2 primitives not 1

Comment: ananthonline: what would the extra two indices be for, exactly?

Comment: According to the documentation, TriangleList means "The data is ordered as a sequence of triangles; each triangle is described by three new vertices. Back-face culling is affected by the current winding-order render state". So, given 4 vertices, your indices are { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 } or something along those lines. Six indices make up two triangles (with 4 vertices). XNA cannot render quads like OpenGL can.